# python subprocess popen with timeout and or kill

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am attempting to grep a continuous stream on the server monitor via popen for 5 seconds, capture the output and perform some operations on it. I am able to do it till here but the subprocess opened by Popen is staying back and continuously running (as it's a monitor stream) and affecting my CPU stats. Below is what I am using to run.

```
class ThreadWorker(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, callable, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ThreadWorker, self).__init__()
    self.callable = callable
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    self.setDaemon(True)

def run(self):
    try:
        self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    #except wx.PyDeadObjectError:
        #pass
    except Exception, e:
        print e

if __name__ == "__main__":

def worker(pipe,fileName,grabtime):
    f = csv.writer(open(fname,'wb'),delimiter='\t',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    while True:
        line = pipe.readline()
        csvlist = [line.rstrip(),int(grabtime)]
        f.writerow(csvlist)


fname = 'test.csv'

proc = Popen(mycmdhere, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

try:
stdout_worker = ThreadWorker(worker, proc.stdout, fname,time.time())
stdout_worker.start()
stdout_worker.join(5)
except Exception, msg:
    print "Timed out!"
```

That's my code. Any help in trying to kill the continuous stream will be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Comment: My python interpretter is stuck at 2.4.3 and I cannot upgrade because it's a shared box!

Comment: You could try building the timeout into your worker() function.